# Unity3D error CS0138 trying to use legacy particle system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity3D project which is trying to use the legacy particle emitter system.

My scripts are failing to compile with error CS0138:

> Assets/MFPS/Scripts/Weapon/bl_Blast.cs(10,1): error CS0138: A using directive can only be applied to namespaces but UnityEngine.ParticleEmitter denotes a type. Consider using a `using static' instead

I am using an asset called "MFPS 1.0.9" and Unity3D version 2018.2.0b9

Here are the `using` directives at the top of my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.ParticleEmitter;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

I also tried writing that second line as:

```
using static UnityEngine.ParticleEmitter;
```

That produces a different error:

> Assets/MFPS/Scripts/Weapon/bl_Blast.cs(10,7): error CS1644: Feature `using static' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification

Comment: If i write 'using static UnityEngine.ParticleEmitter;', unity 3D return: Assets/MFPS/Scripts/Weapon/bl_Blast.cs(10,7): error CS1644: Feature `using static' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleEmitter.html), the correct namespace is:

```
using UnityEngine.ParticlesLegacyModule;
```

Not

```
using UnityEngine.ParticleEmitter;
```

But keep in minde that the legacy particle system is obsolete and will be removed soon. Consider using the new [particle system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ParticleSystem.html).